# drag and drop file into textbox

Tags: c#

I want to drag and drop a file so that the textbox shows the full file path. I have used the drag enter and drag drop events but I find that they are not entering the events.

```
private void sslCertField_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop, false) == true)
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All;
    } 
}

private void sslCertField_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    string file = (string)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
    serverURLField.Text = file;
}
```

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE: Does not work if program is set to run with elevated permissions (vista/win 7)**

Comment: can you show us some markup ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Check the [`AllowDrop`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.allowdrop.aspx) property of your textbox - it should be set to `true`.
Also, convert drag-drop data to `string[]` in case of `DataFormats.FileDrop`, not just `string`:

```
string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
if(files != null && files.Length != 0)
{
    serverURLField.Text = files[0];
}
```

And I think you should swap code in your drag event handlers - usually you show user that drag-drop is possible in `DragEnter` and perform actual operation on `DragDrop`.

Comment: I have done everything you said. I changed allowdrop to true, and changed the content of the methods as well as changing it to string[]. however, the events are still not activated. this form is part of a parent form. would that affect it? However, this text box is not part of the parent's controls

Comment: in fact when i try drag a file, i get the denied icon

Comment: Is your application running under elevated (administrator) privileges on Win7/Vista? Drag-drop from explorer won't work in this case.

Comment: yes I am running with elevated priviledges. so there is nothing I can do to overcome this problem?

Comment: Nothing that I'm aware of, at least.

Comment: ok thanks :) good to know at least the reason why it won't work

Answer (score 15):

Elevated privileges should not have anything to do with it.  You also need to implement the `DragOver` event in addition to the `DragDrop` that Max answered. This is the code that should be added for DragDrop:

`private void textBoxFile_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
  else
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
}`

Comment: In Windows Form applications, the following needs to be done to get it to work:  1) Set `TextBox.AllowDrop = true;`  2) Handle the `TextBox.DragDrop()` event using max's code  3) Also handle the `TextBox.DragOver()` event using Joao's code above.  When all 3 conditions are met it should work.  No "elevated priveleges" were required in my case, but you could always alter your Visual Studio shortcut to "run as Administrator" if you discover it is a problem for you.

Answer (score 7):

dont run it from visual studio... run the .exe which is created once you build your solution.. hope that helps :)

Comment: Does running the project in Visual Studio make a difference ? Really ? Is Visual Studio supposed to disable drag-drop functionality ?

Comment: yeah somehow it didn't work from debug but it worked directly

Comment: I rewrote my control 3 times trying to figure this out... :( Thanks.

Comment: This is likely because (as in my case) running VS as an admin as  noted by Martijn.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using WPF and it still doesn't work with the answers here (which was my case), you need to use

```
e.Handled = true;
```

in the `PreviewDragEnter` event, as described [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42696/Textbox-Drag-Drop-in-WPF) and [here](http://peteohanlon.wordpress.com/2009/09/28/textbox-dragdrop-in-wpf/) (they're the same article, but just in case one goes down).

Here is the code snippet, from that source :

```
private void TextBox_PreviewDragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    e.Handled = true;
}

private void TextBox_PreviewDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    object text = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
    TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
    if (tb != null)
    {
        tb.Text = string.Format("{0}", ((string[])text)[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: It shouldn't be PreviewDragEnter, it should be *PreviewDragOver*. Using that event worked for me for TextBox.

Comment: Thank you both. This was my issue.
Changed DragOver to PreviewDragOver and added the e.Handled line, now it works. :)

Answer (score 2):

If your visual studio is running under Administrator rights Drag and drop functionality seems not to work.

=> Run visual studio without Admin rights and it will work

Edit:
A workaround to test your drag and drop functionality is

- Open notepad as administrator
- File -> open
- from the open dialog you will be able to drag and drop files in your application